# javascript svg animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

How would I write script that would move a shape in svg linearly with javascript. I want to use requestanimframe.

Here is an example using canvas. I just want to do the same thing except with svg.

The script obtains a context to the canvas then it uses javascript to draw a shape with the properties of the context. Then it manages the animation of the shape on the canvas in a linear motion. I just want to use svg for the shape instead of the canvas context properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #myCanvas {
            border: 1px solid #9C9898;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
        })();

        function animate(lastTime, myRectangle){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // update
            var date = new Date();
            var time = date.getTime();
            var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
            var linearSpeed = 100; // pixels / second
            var linearDistEachFrame = linearSpeed * timeDiff / 1000;
            var currentX = myRectangle.x;

            if (currentX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
                var newX = currentX + linearDistEachFrame;
                myRectangle.x = newX;
            }
            lastTime = time;

            // clear
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // draw
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);

            context.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
            context.strokeStyle = "black";
            context.stroke();

            // request new frame
            requestAnimFrame(function(){
                animate(lastTime, myRectangle);
            });
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            var myRectangle = {
                x: 0,
                y: 50,
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                borderWidth: 5
            };

            var date = new Date();
            var time = date.getTime();
            animate(time, myRectangle);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="return false;">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200">
    </canvas>

</body>
```

Comment: Instead of using `requestAnimationFrame` why wouldn't you just use SVG's built in animation primitives?

Comment: I was reading an article on http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/graphics-and-imaging/3254-svg-javascript-and-the-dom.html. I am trying to understand how to apply this to the concepts I am learning about how to animate javascript / canvas.

Comment: But here you're animating SVG, not canvas?

Comment: Let me reword it. I am learning about how to animate javascript / canvas. That is where the code example is from. I was reading an article on i-programmer.info/programming/graphics-and-imaging/…. and I was interested in seeing how you would animate svg instead of canvas using similar javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to move an element in SVG with JavaScript is to modify the transform attribute of the element.  This isn't the best method in terms of performance, but it is very readable and simple.

Most simply:

```
var el = document.getElementById( "mySVGElement" );
for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
  setTimeout( function( ) {
    el.setAttribute( "transform", "translate( " + i + ", 0 )" );
  }, 200 + i );
}
```

Or if you want a function to do it:

```
function translateElement( element, distance )
{
  var x, y;
  for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  {
    setTimeout( function( ) {
      x = parseInt( distance.x * i / 100 );
      y = parseInt( distance.y * i / 100 );
      element.setAttribute( "transform", "translate( " + x + ", " + y + " )" );
    }, 20 + i );
  }
}
```

or per Erik's advice:

```
function translateElement( element, distance )
{
  var x, y;
  for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  {
    setTimeout( function( ) {
      x = distance.x * i / 100;
      y = distance.y * i / 100;
      element.transform.baseVal.getItem( 0 ).setTranslate( x, y );
    }, 20 + i );
  }
}
```

Where element is the element you're moving and distance is an object of the form:

```
{
  x: xOffset,
  y: yOffset
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the float->string->float conversions by using SVG DOM methods instead, assuming you have a transform="translate(0,0)" attribute to begin with you can use this to change the translation: el.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setTranslate(x,y). Anyway, modifying the transform is likely to be the most efficient way for moving svg shapes around.

Comment: Thanks, Erik!  Glad to have a tip from the SVG master.

Comment: Regarding your third example, do you have any feeling for the efficiency of setInterval relative to setTimout? I'd be inclined to the former to have fewer function calls floating about, but then I'm pretty green behind the ears when it comes to javascript!